# Python script not running in boot with executable file, but if i execute the file manually it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey so the title is pretty descriptive of the issue, running on PI 3B+

Here is the launcher.sh that does run if i execute it by hand :

```
#!/bin/sh
#launcher.sh

cd /
cd home/pi/SummerSeries2021
sudo python3 Main.py
cd /
```

Here is the logs of the launch when it boots

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 21, in <module>
    elif pirB.motion_detected:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 350, in is_active
    return self.value > self.threshold
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 604, in value
    return super(MotionSensor, self).value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 325, in value
    return self._queue.value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 587, in value
    return self.average(self.queue)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/statistics.py", line 311, in mean
    T, total, count = _sum(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/statistics.py", line 147, in _sum
    for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration
```

And here is the python script it self :

```
import sys
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
from adafruit_motor import stepper
import time
import board

kit = MotorKit()
pirS = MotionSensor(4)
pirB = MotionSensor(21)
#flushcons = 3 
while True: 
    while True:
        if pirS.motion_detected:
            print("Petite")
            for i in range(100):
                kit.stepper1.onestep(style = stepper.DOUBLE)
            for j in range(100):
                kit.stepper1.onestep(direction = stepper.BACKWARD,style = stepper.DOUBLE)
            break
        elif pirB.motion_detected:
            print("Grosse")
            for k in range(100):
                kit.stepper2.onestep(style = stepper.DOUBLE)
            for l in range(100):
                kit.stepper2.onestep(direction = stepper.BACKWARD,style = stepper.DOUBLE)
            break
        else:
            print("RAS")
    kit.stepper1.release()
    kit.stepper2.release()
```

Here is the line i added to the crontab

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/SummerSeries2021/launcher.sh >home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

Basically it activates one of the 2 stepper motors depending which PIR sensor you wave, but my main concerne is that if i run the script in my IDE it works, if I execute the launcher by hand after boot, it works but not when the launcher.sh execute on boot using the crontab.

Anyone ran into this issue before ?

Thanks